# Equation of wave motion in one direction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

While deriving time independent schrodinger equation for a particle, my textbook starts with the following. From where they got equation 3.1? I thought equation 3.1 should have a second order partial in time  $\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial t^2}$. How did they replace this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation). Unfortunately the text isn't doing you any favors by seemingly pulling it out of nowhere, and on top of that, referring to it as an "equation of wave motion", which is dangerously close to "wave equation". Although perhaps the author can be forgiven because this is just the wave equation in frequency domain.

The wave equation in one dimension is
$$\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} - \frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t}^2\right)\psi = 0$$

If you assume harmonic time dependence, namely $\psi(x, t) = \phi(x)e^{-i\omega t}$, and plug it in, you get
$$\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\omega^2}{v^2}\right)\phi e^{-i\omega t} = 0$$
$$\left(\frac{d^2}{d x^2} + \frac{\omega^2}{v^2}\right)\phi = 0.$$

Finally, using $v=\lambda f=\frac{\lambda\omega}{2\pi}$, you get
$$\left(\frac{d^2}{d x^2} + \frac{4\pi^2}{\lambda^2}\right)\phi = 0.$$

Comment: thank you so much it is clear now... ill upvote as soon as i get some reputation